# Trying to pull out newest errors in Log file and the create custom.txt output

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am new to powershell scripting and have been tasked to create some alerts based on errors in certain logfiles. These are just logs from a bespoke application.

My current Code is

```
`$OutputFile3 = (Get-Location).Path + ".\Results.txt"

 $Sourcefolder= "C:\Users\dewana\Documents\Test\"
 $Targetfolder= "C:\Users\dewana\Documents\Test\Test3"
 Get-ChildItem -Path $Sourcefolder -Recurse|
 Where-Object {
 $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)
 }| Copy-Item -Destination $Targetfolder


 $Testing5 = Get-Content -Tail -1 -Path "C:\Users\dewana\Documents\Test\Test3\*.txt"  | Where-Object 
 { $_.Contains("errors") }

Remove-Item $OutputFile3
New-Item $OutputFile3 -ItemType file 
try
 {
    $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $OutputFile3
    $stream.WriteLine('clientID 1111')
    $stream.WriteLine('SEV 1')
    $stream.WriteLine('Issue with this process')
 }
finally
{
$stream.close()
}`
```

What i am struggling with is trying is

`$Testing5 = Get-Content -Tail -1 -Path "C:\Users\dewana\Documents\Test\Test3\*.txt"  | Where-Object { $_.Contains("errors") }` 
I am trying to store the latest string which contains the word error in the log file. i would want to use the stored string to the create an if statement to say if $Testing5 have a new value of error assigned the create a custom text file.

I can't seem to find out why the get-content is not working with the where-object

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is your `Where-Object` code block is on the next line.

```
Get-Content -Tail -1 -Path $tempfile | Where-Object
{ $_.Contains("errors") }
```

If you separate at the pipe it's fine.

```
Get-Content -Tail -1 -Path $tempfile |
    Where-Object { $_.Contains("errors") }
```